Ranges that work in the $\mathsf{NP}$ hardness variant of integer factorization
In this post  on whether a variant of integer factorization
$$\mathsf{}\mbox{ }{\Pi} = \{\langle a, b, n \rangle \;|\; \exists \mbox{ } \mathsf{ an}\mbox{ }\mathsf{ integer}\mbox{ } m \in [a, b]\mbox{ }\mathsf{ such}\mbox{ }\mathsf{that}\mbox{ }m | n\}$$
is $\mathsf{NP}$ complete, it is clear that difference $b-a$ can neither be too small nor too big for the problem to remain $\mathsf{NP}$ complete under Cramér's conjecture.
What is the possible range of difference $b-a$ under which the problem remains $\mathsf{NP}$ complete under Cramér's conjecture?

If $a=N^\gamma+O(N^\theta)$, can $b=a+O(N^{\theta'})$ hold and the problem be $\mathsf{NP}$ hard with any $\gamma,\theta,\theta'$ at $0\leq\theta\leq\theta'\leq\gamma$ and $\gamma\in(0,1)$?


In particular could the interval $[\sqrt{N},2\sqrt{N}]$ work?

Note in this problem $m$ need not be prime which makes the problem combinatorial rather than arithmetical
